# Does this algorithm have time and space complexity O(n) or O(1)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

> **Update**: 
>   - Wikipedia says `o(n)` not `O(n)` so this algorithm isn't an in-place solution.
>   - Debating whether this solution runs in `O(n)` or `O(1)`.

This is my solution for LeetCode question [Flatten Binary Tree to Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/). In terms of time and space complexity analysis, I'm not quite sure it's `O(1)` according to some explanations. I think it's `O(n)` because of the use of the stack. Is my analysis correct?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), `O(n)` is still accepted as **in-place**.

> More broadly, in-place means that the algorithm does not use extra space for manipulating the input but may require a small though nonconstant extra space for its operation. Usually, this space is O(log n), though sometimes anything in o(n) is allowed.

```js
/**
 * Function flattens a binary tree.
 * Time = O(n) because we iterate through all nodes.
 * Space = O(n) because we use a stack.
 * @param {root} root Input tree.
 */
var flatten = function(root) {
    // If reach end of leaf node, return.
    if (root === null) return;

    let stack = [];
    let currentNode = root;

    while (true) {
        // Push right branch to stack first,
        if (currentNode.right) stack.push(currentNode.right);
        // then left branch.
        if (currentNode.left) stack.push(currentNode.left);
        // If there are branches in stack:
        if (stack.length > 0) {
            // Change the current currentNode right branch to the last element of the stack:
            currentNode.right = stack.pop();
            // Change left branch to null
            currentNode.left = null;
            // Advance by changing current currentNode to the right currentNode.
            currentNode = currentNode.right;
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Re: "According to Wikipedia, `O(n)` is still accepted as **in-place**": Your quotation doesn't support that claim. Note that *o* ("little *o*") is different from *O* ("big *O*"); see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation.

Comment: You have a good point. However, this article says the same thing: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-algorithm/
Also, in your opinion, the code above has `O(1)` or `O(n)`?

Comment: Re: "However, this article says the same thing: [geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-algorithm/)": No, that article says the same thing as Wikipedia. In fact, it literally just quotes Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the algorithm uses `Theta(N)` worst-case time and worst-case additional space where `N` is the number of nodes in the tree. The time complexity is is clear, because you push and pop each node once.

The space complexity is a bit more tricky, but consider for example a tree that is a list where the next elements of the list are the left children, but assume it has additionally for each of these list nodes one right child which itself does not have any children.

With that example your algorithm will walk through the left-hand nodes, adding the right-hand ones to the stack, but only popping those once the end of the original list is reached, i.e. there will be about `N/2` elements in the stack.

Best-case, the time complexity is still `Theta(N)`, because you always iterate over all nodes, but the best-case space complexity is `Theta(1)`, because e.g. a tree that is already a list will never increase the stack size to more than `1`.

This would usually not be considered an *in-place* algorithm, because it uses additional `Theta(N)` space, at least worst-case. As explained in the Wikipedia article, an *in-place* algorithm should require `o(N)` additional space or, I would say, usually only `O(1)` or slightly more than that, e.g. `O((ln N)^k)` for some `k` maximum. Whether one should count worst-case or average-case is another question.

`o(N)` is the *little-o notation*, not the *big-O notation*. It means the the time/space is asymptotically smaller than `c*N` for *every* `c > 0`. `Theta(N)` is therefore never `o(N)`.

Also, `Theta(N)` means that not only is it `O(N)`, meaning asymptotically smaller then `c*N` for *some* `c > 0`, but also that it is asymptotically larger than `c*N` for some `c`.

If you want an in-place algorithm by the stricter definition, you should not require any additional container of dynamic size.

Comment: @Viet Please read my corrected answer. I did not read your algorithm correctly and made some wrong claims in my previous answer.

Comment: I've asked some senior folks and some say time complexity for this solution is actually `O(log(n))` or `O(h)` (h = height of tree). The reason I ask is: I think your answer is correct but I'm receiving different explanations, so before I mark it as correct, I want to make sure.

Comment: @Viet Do you mean the space complexity? Because yes, the space complexity is `O(h)` in the height of the tree. This does not contradict my claims. But there are trees with `n` nodes that have height `h = n`. As demonstrated in my answer there are trees on `n` nodes for which the space complexity is `Omega(N)` (i.e. asymptotically larger than `c*N` for some `c > 0`). If you assume that the tree is balanced, then indeed space complexity is `Theta(log(N))` worst case, because balanced trees have height `h = O(log(n))`.

Comment: If you assume all trees (whether balanced or not) to be chosen uniformly this is also true average-case, but not worst-case.

Comment: As for time complexity, I don't see how it can be `o(N)`. I think it is clear that you push and pop each node ones, so there must be at least on the order of `N` actions in there. (`n` in my previous comments was supposed to be `N`.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I meant *space*, not *time*. I can't edit my comment. Weird. One last thing: worst-case: the tree is unbalanced - the tree has only one left branch and at the 2nd to last node, it has a child on the right (last node), then if we push the whole left branch to the stack, doesn't that hold (n - 1) space (excluding the root value)? That means worst-case, the algorithm runs in O(n) space?

Comment: @Viet Comments can be edited only for 5 minutes after posting. I am not sure I follow your example. If there is only one branching point, then you will almost never push more often than you pop per iteration, so the stack will have constant-bounded size. But yes, worst-time space complexity is `O(N)`. I gave the example why it cannot be better than that in the answer.

Comment: Thank you @walnut. My example is similar to what you wrote `h = n` a *skewed tree*, but mine is not really a skewed tree because the last one is on the right branch (some say it's the best case) but I agree with you that's the worst case. My example is like finding the element from 0 to n but the target is at n.

Comment: @Viet Note that the space complexity is `Theta(h)` worst-case, but not best-case. If you have a fully-skewed tree (or any linear tree), then your algorithm will push one entry per iteration and pop one per iteration, so space complexity will be `Theta(1)` in the height (and the number of nodes) best-case. You need to add leafs to all or a significant fraction of nodes of the linear tree to get an order-of-`N` space complexity.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help!